# Value "not a number" in my dataframe not found

Tags: python, dataframe, nan, data-cleaning

I have a problem because I can't find the NaN values that appear when I use describe() on my dataframe.
I'm working with Jupyter.

Here is what it looks like

[my dataframe describe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c0wCn.png)

And when I use .isnull() and info() functions I got :

[isnull() utilization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKwZm.png)

[info()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ff5Ku.png)

Can you help me please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you confirmed, it seems that there is no NaN in `df`.

I think you are confused with what `df.describes` returns. `df.describes` returns a summary of the dataframe.
`df` is not `df.describe()`.

When you use `describe()`, the `NaN` values mean it is impossible to calculate. For example, there are values of `object` types, such as Month, Date, and Age_Group. It is impossible to calculate mean value of Month because Month's data type is `object`, not `int`.

Comment: Thank you for your very clear answer !

Answer (score 0):

You're using describe to get basic descriptive statistics in order to make inferences, such as the number of years on your dataframe which is set to NaN in unique because probably all of the rows have the exact same year. So yes, there aren't NaNs in your dataset.

Comment: Thank you for your answer I had not thought of this aspect.